# Registration of app failed because the files are on a network share. Copy the files to the local computer before registering the package

Tags: c#, windows

I am using these examples to build a Windows 8 app:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Getting-started-with-C-and-41e15af5

(note: that link is stale, this is potentially the correct one: [Getting started with C# and Visual Basic: Hello World samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Getting-started-with-C-and-aec28023)   )

When I try and run the Windows 8 device emulator, I get this error:

> Error  1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Rejecting a request to register from file://psf/Home/Desktop/Getting%20started%20with%20C#%20and%20Visual%20Basic%20Hello%20World%20and%20Blog%20reader%20samples%20(1)/C#/HelloWorld_Part1/bin/Debug/AppX/AppxManifest.xml because the files are on a network share. Copy the files to the local computer before registering the package. (0x80073cf9)   HelloWorld_Part1

I am using Paralells on a Mac. What folder is not a network share?

Comment: That path looks as if it's on a Macintosh volume, as opposed to a Windows partition.  From the point of view of the virtual Windows machine, the Macintosh volumes are network shares.  Copy the files to the Windows partition (drive C) and try running them from there.

Comment: Same problem occurs in Fusion 5 if My Documents is mapped to a folder shared with the Mac (and, no, please don't tell me not to do this). This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236506/visual-studio-test-wont-run-over-a-network-share is similar but the solution there doesn't solve the problem for Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?  I, too, use Parallels on a Mac as my main development environment. In Visual Studio 2010, I remedied my network share issues as outlined: http://www.sehajpal.com/index.php/2010/10/how-to-solve-loadfromremotesources-error-in-vs-2010/

If you find a way to run executables/register executables from a network share for Visual Studio 2012, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 Network Shares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786800/visual-studio-2012-network-shares)

Comment: Remote debugging and setting the debug target to localhost totally did the trick for me with Parallels and a osx<->win shared folder.

Answer (score 23):

I am using Parallels with a Windows 10 image and VS Community 2013.
I solved the problem with the solution proposed by @tempy above: choosing remote host in the launch configuration and writing localhost in the following screen, when it asks for the machine name.
I am able to run, debug, set breakpoints, as usual

**For Visual Studio 2015:**

- Right-click the project
- Select Properties
- Select the Debug settings
- Under *Start options*

  - Set *Target Device* to "Remote Machine"
  - Set *Remote machine* to "localhost"

Comment: Still works in VS2017, Windows 10. My problem was that I have a local drive/folder mapped as a network drive. This fixed it.

Comment: Still works in VS2019 too. Remember to install the VS Remote Debugger on the Windows 10 image and have it running, or else you might get an error like "Deployment target 'Local Machine' does not support projects targetting X64 platform. Supported platforms: X86."

Answer (score 0):

I copied the files to C:\inpetpub\wwwroot and ran them from there. You cannot run the projects from pdf. VS 2012 cannot run files on a network share. I guess Paralells gets Mac files on a type of network share.