# Parallels 6 VS2010 on Windows 7 Web Site Error '...Failed to start monitoring changes to path\to\web.config"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-debugging, parallels

I've got Parallels 6 running VS2010 under Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro.  I'm trying to run my .NET 4.0 MVC 3 web site (debug/release) using the VS default web server and I keep getting the following error:  **'An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to path\to\web.config'**.  I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018426/how-can-i-debug-solutions-in-visual-studio-2010-from-a-network-share), but the solution does not apply (indeed it does not appear to be a fix for my particular problem) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. It has to do with the way Parallels sets up sharing of documents between OSX and Windows. I don't know how to fix the problem itself, but an easy workaround is to move your projects directory outside the Documents folder. I created C:\Projects\ and everything runs fine from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this was my solution, even though there has to be a "real" solution "out there."